# Json string to object array c#

Tags: c#

My test json is as below..

```
 string json = "[{Name:'John Simith',Age:35},{Name:'Pablo Perez',Age:34}]";
```

The json could have any key values and so I do not have a class to deserialize it with.. I can deserialize it as IEnumerable as below

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(json);
```

I need to convert it to 2D object arrays : object[,] as below..

```
[
['John Simith',35],['Pablo Perez',34]
]
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change from `dynamic` to `IDictionary<string, object>` in order to be able to enumerate unknown keys. Then a LINQ expression can convert it to an array, like this:

```
var json = "[{Name:'John Simith',Age:35},{Name:'Pablo Perez',Age:34}]";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>(json);

var array = data.Select(d => d.Values.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: hello. but how to preserve the property names? if I use .toDictionary(), then how?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a C# class to deserialize it to, the best thing to do is to use the dynamic LINQ objects that JSON.NET provides, meaning `JObject`, `JArray` and so on. This lets you query the structure dynamically, read types values and so on, without having to fight with C#'s type system:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm

It would be much easier to traverse the JSON tree and convert to `object[,]` from those objects.